# How to assign up-values for `Derivative`?

Tags: symbolic, upvalues

I have defined several custom analytic functions.  Here is the simplest example:

```
ln[x_, a_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{Log[x], Re[a] > 0}, {-Log[1/x], True}}]
```

Now I would like to let Mathematica know how to carry out derivatives on this:  I need to make `D` and `Series` work on `ln` as if it were `Log`:

```
ln /: D[ln[f_, g_], x_] := D[Log[f], x];
```

Works wonderfully:

[image]

But `Series` doesn't work because it is using `Derivative` instead of `D`.

[image]

So, now I try `TagSetDelayed` on `Derivative`:

[image]

But as you can see, it doesn't work because `ln` is too deep.  What can I do to make `Series` work?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understood your question (though I answered already)... If you're just worried why the `Series` didn't simplify with your definition for `D`, then it's because you didn't define `ln` for symbolic `a`. That's why I used a numeric `a` in my answer in the series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to use `TagSetDelayed` for the definition of the derivative because `Derivative` doesn't have attribute `Protected`.

I'll extend add the derivative definition to arbitrary order `n`:

```
ClearAll[ln];
Derivative[n_, 0][ln][x_, a_] := Derivative[n][Log][x]

ln[x_, a_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{Log[x], Re[a] > 0}, {-Log[1/x], True}}]

ln[x, -1/2]
```

> $-\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

```
D[ln[x, a], x]
```

> $\frac{1}{x}$

```
D[ln[Cos[x] + x, a], x]
```

> $$\frac{1-\sin (x)}{x+\cos (x)}$$

```
Series[ln[Cos[x] + x, 1/2], {x, 0, 2}]
```

> $x-x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$

```
Series[ln[Cos[x] + x, a], {x, 0, 2}]
```

> $\ln (1,a)+x-x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$

The symbolic argument `a` also gives a result now because the definitions for the derivatives work for symbolic `a`, as well. Only the zeroth-order term is not simplified because it only knows what that evaluates to when `a` is numeric.

Comment: Very nice!  What I'm really trying to do is to define a function that works as seamlessly as possible with Mathematica's analytic functions like `Integrate` `Limit` `Series` etc.. do you know of a simple way to do this?  Should I ask it as a separate question?