# How to make a new analytic function work seamlessly with Mathematica's analysis functions?

Tags: function-construction

I am defining a new analytic function of six variables.  I have algorithms to evaluate it numerically, and have amassed a large catalog of analytic properties.

It is easy for me to program the numerics using:

```
funcF[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, e_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ] = (*...*)
```

I know the analytic expression for its derivative with respect to each argument.  I also know the location of all the singularities and the Taylor/asymptotic series expansion of this function near these singularities in all six variables, and a bunch of other identities.

**Question**:  I want to make a package that incorporates this function into *Mathematica*.  What do I need to do to to make it work as seamlessly as possible with its built-in functions like `Derivative`, `Limit`, `Series` `Simplify`, *etc.*  Clearly, there will be a lot of coding to do, but I'm more than willing.

---

I already have a head-start from the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59373/how-to-assign-up-values-for-derivative), which nicely makes the custom function `ln` work well with `Derivative` and `Series`.  I stumbled upon this page: http://functions.wolfram.com/NB/StruveH.nb which includes functions like `DomainAndRange`, `Singularities`, etc. and thought this would be the key to accomplishing my task.  Alas, these functions aren't `Mathematica` functions and can't be evaluated.  Is there a template/guideline for this?

Comment: If you can get `Series` to swallow it, you'll pretty much get `Limit` for free. One thing though: make sure it has the `NumericFunction` attribute set. As for `Simplify`, there may be ways to teach it tricks. Possibly more important though, if applicable, would be to have `UpValues` for use by `FunctionExpand`.

Comment: Thanks; it's working, but seems backwards that I get `Series` if I have `Derivative`, and `Limit` if I have `Series`.  What are the benefits of giving attribute `NumericFunction`?  It seems bit superficial to me.

Comment: There will be places in internal `Limit` (and other) code that check for that attribute, and treat nonnumeric "functions" as being, in effect, inert. So if you have `myFunction[x]`, that might be seen as something for `Limit` et al to regard as constant rather than being functionally dependent on `x`.

Comment: Thanks!  Also, when would it be useful to define `UpValues` for use by `FunctionExpand`?  Is it called by internal code of built-in *Mathematica* functions?

Comment: I really cannot say whether or to what extent `UpValues` might be useful in `FunctionExpand`. I think it will depend on exactly what you are trying to do. As for internal usage, yes, `FunctionExpand` is used in several places inside `Limit`, `Integrate`, and I think elsewhere as well.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm trying to define an `UpValue` of a symbolic function `f` with: `f /: FunctionExpand[f[x_]] := Sin[x] Cos[x]`.  But `FunctionExpand[f[x] + 1]` doesn't work.  Can you suggest how I'm supposed to define an `UpValue` for user-defined symbols?

Comment: That case will be a problem since `UpValues` only reacts to things a level deep. Maybe it would it be workable to define a custom `myFunctionExpand` that becomes `FunctionExpand` on input free from `f` but maps the up-valued definition onto parts containing `f` With careful use of true/false switches you might even get `FunctionExpand` to become `myFunctionExpand`.