# Taylor series of functions with defined derivatives?

Tags: series-expansion, calculus-and-analysis

Suppose that I have the following equations
$$\dot{x}(t) = p(t),$$
$$\dot{p}(t) = -V'(x(t)).$$
I am trying to compute the Taylor series of $p(t)$ at $t=0$.

Here are the codes I use:

```
x'[t_] := p[t]; p'[t_] := -V'[x[t]];

Series[p[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

Then I get the result in Mathematica

`p[0] - V'[x[0]] t + 1/2 p''[0] t^2 + O[t]^3`

But `p''` in the result isn't computed.

If I use

```
D[p[t], {t, 2}]
```

then I get what I want for $p''$: `-p[t]V''[x[t]]`.

How could I get the Taylor series of any order which compute the higher order derivatives properly?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? You haven't set `p''` to be anything.

Comment: Note that the `FullForm` of `p''[t]` is `Derivative[2][p][t]`.  For it to work the way you expected, `p` would have to be defined, not just `p'[t]`, which defines a value only for `Derivative[1][p][..]`. Or you would have to do some other work around.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for your reminding!

Comment: Closely relate, possibly duplicate: [How to assign up-values for `Derivative`?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59373/245)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should define *all* derivatives of `x` and `p`, and not just the first:

```
Derivative[n_Integer][x][t_] := Derivative[n - 1][p][t]
Derivative[n_Integer][p][t_] := D[-V'[x[u]], {u, n - 1}] /. u -> t
```

Then

```
Series[p[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

> [image]

You can choose any order.

Comment: It works! Thanks you very much!